# Cors error with Angular4 http request public rest api

Tags: angular, typescript, cors, ember-cli, angular-cli

Ĥello, I am a bit confused and I don't know how I can solve the problem with the cors. It is definitly not a problem with the server because I am getting it with every rest api which is outside my application.

I am using following rest api for test

[http://www.groupkt.com/post/f2129b88/free-restful-web-services-to-consume-and-test.htm][1]

> Code:

```
async getData(){
  const url = "http://www.groupkt.com/post/c9b0ccb9/country-and-other-related-rest-webservices.htm";
  const response = await this.http.get(url).toPromise();
  console.log(response)
}
}
```

> HTML

```
<button (click)="getData();"></button>
```

Following error I am getting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://www.groupkt.com/post/c9b0ccb9/country-and-other-related-rest-webservices.htm.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.   [1]:
>   http://www.groupkt.com/post/f2129b88/free-restful-web-services-to-consume-and-test.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Url http://services.groupkt.com/country/get/all (For exemple) , this is a WebService sample. The url you use in you're code is only the description of The services.